# Deploying to aws via codebuild fails with with following error : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve /node_modules/nib/node_modules/stylus

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-codebuild, stylus, kue

Running node version 16.13.2
Checking for version of stylus :
-- kue@0.11.6
+-- nib@1.1.2
| `-- stylus@0.54.5`  -- stylus@0.54.8

I'm getting this error when deploying in codebuild :

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve /node_modules/nib/node_modules/stylus

I've read that that version of stylus works with node version 14 but we are on version 16 - however I can't find any later versions of kue.

Has anyone encountered this error and discovered any possible solution? I've been scouring release notes etc with no luck so far over the past days.